# NSURLRequest setHttpBody

Tags: iphone, nsurlrequest, multipartform-data, form-data

I got a wrong post(php:echo $_POST) like below:
**Array (     [email"aa@qq_com] => -----------------------------14737809831466499882746641449 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="password" c8837b23ff8aaa8a2dde915473ce0991  )**

my code:

```
// set header value ,   some random text that will never occur in the body  
NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";   NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];   [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];         /*   now lets create the body of the post      */   NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];              //  email part         
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];        
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"email\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];   
[body appendData:[anEmail dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];     
[body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];          //  password part     [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];     
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"password\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];    
[body appendData:[aPassword dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];     
[body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];          //  image part     [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];        
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat: @"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadingImage\"; filename=%@\r\n", anImageName]                        dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];    
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];   
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:aFileData]];     
[body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];             
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];  
// setting the body of the post to the reqeust  
[request setHTTPBody:body];         // now lets make the connection to the web  
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: @Neptune. Array ( [email"aa@qq_com] => -----------------------------14737809831466499882746641449 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="password" c8837b23ff8aaa8a2dde915473ce0991 )  I want $value is aa@qq.com whilt $key is email, and $value is c8837b23ff8aaa8a2dde915473ce0991 while $key is password.

Comment: @Neptune. I can't get my $_POST['email'] or $_POST['password']. But I　can get $_FILES['uploadingImage'], and it's correct. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it should be

```
name=\"password\"\r\n\r\n%@",password];
```

but now you are doing like this

```
name=\"password\"\r\n%@\r\n",password];
```

Hope you understood the mistake..

Comment: I just figured it out.
`[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"email\"\r\n"]` 
should be like this:
`[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"email\"\r\n\r\n"]`

Comment: thanks.
I wonder there is some explanation on it.
It's ok to use this format, but I still want to know more.
Do you have any tutorial?